# Local isometry & geodesic

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, geodesic

Question: If $F$ and $G$ are regular surfaces, $f:F\to G$ a local isometry and $c:I\to F$ a geodesic, how can I show that also $f \circ c:I\to G$ is a geodesic?

Comment: To be a local isometry implies to preserve (locally) the lengths. What is the main (local) property of a geodesic?

Comment: If $f$ is a local isometry, then when restricting to some open sets, $f:U \rightarrow  V$ an isometry and so it maps geodesics to geodesics.

Comment: A geodesic is a generalisation of the notion of a straight line to curved spaces and can be thought as the locally shortest or extremal path between (two) points.

Comment: So you mean that the claim follows from the fact that f is a local isometry?

Comment: Well I'm not so sure that follows, but for the global case. Assume that if $\gamma$ is a smooth curve on $U$ and if $v$ is a vector field along $\gamma$ then $$\phi_{*} D_t v=\bar{D}_{t}\phi_{*} v$$ where $D, \bar{D}$ are the covariant derivatives of $\gamma$ and $\gamma \circ v$ respectively.  If you can show this for local, then it should follow for global.